# mount points & installation

Tags: mount

I've two HDD one of 160GB and another of 1TB.I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 in 160GB HDD and create two saparte partition of 500MB each. I want to know how is this possible and what should be the mount points for all of them as HDD space is unallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Different people use different schemes for partitioning their hard drives depending on their preference, so the answers here will probably vary. For sure you need a "/" partition, and I would recommend a "swap" partition as opposed to a swap file. Also, it is not a bad idea to have a separate "/home" partition. Some users have a separate "/boot" partition, I never bother.So for me, I have the following partitions:

```
/

/home

swap
```

During the installation process you will be prompted to format your hard drive. It is at this stage that you generate the different partitions on the different drives. I guess your 160Gb will be /dev/sda and your 1TB will be /dev/sdb. You could put "/" and "swap" partitions on /dev/sda and "/home" on /dev/sdb, or you could put "/" on /dev/sda and "/home" and "swap" on /dev/sdb, its totally up to you. I guess there are performance gains to be had by having your swap partition on the 1TB, but it's up to you.

When prompted, select /dev/sda, create a new partition, select a size, format it as ext4 and mount it as "/". (I think it is labeled "use as" not "mount as"). Leave enough space for your swap partition, lets say twice as much as your memory. (So if you have 4G RAM, reserve 8G for swap).

Do the same for swap. Select /dev/sda, create the partition, mount it as "swap".

Do the same for "/home". Select /dev/sdb, create a partition, format it as ext4, mount it as "/home".

You should be good to go from here on in.